# Evaluating the derivative of implicitly given function

Tags: calculus

Given implicit function $y$ $=$ $f(x)$ by equality $(x^2+y^2)^2=3x^2y-y^3$.

Evaluate the derivative of 
this function at point $(x,y) = (0,0).$

(copied the following from the comments, JL)

Using implicit differentiation I got
$$y' = (4x^2y+4y^3-3x^2+3y^2)/(6xy-4x^3-4xy^2),$$
but this leads to division by zero at the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$. What's going on?

Comment: It's a singular point. Is there any reason to think that the derivative exists?

Comment: Also, we expect you to give a bit more context when asking.

Comment: I thought it's clear to understand. Sorry, I was wrong. But I just copied out the statement of problem. I do not know how to ask else :)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Context? There isn't any more context needed to answer this question. However, it would be nice if at least some effort was shown so we can know what the OP is having trouble with.

Comment: The curve has three branches thru the origin, all with different slopes. To get a derivative you need to specify a branch. I recommend that you parametrize the curve in polar form, for that makes it visually clear.

Comment: @MPW Context can come in many forms. Efforts/thoughts/origin of the problem/related results covered in class/whatnot. For example, here it would IMHO suffice to show that trying to use implicit differentiation leads to division by zero. My deleted answer shows the reason.

Comment: @MPW My understanding is that providing context includes showing where you get stuck. But I am not a native speaker, so I may get it wrong...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen , AlexVong : Okay, I understand what you mean, and I agree with you. I misunderstood you to mean that the problem wasn't completely stated.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not answerable because the origin is a singularity - both partial derivatives vanish there. In polar coordinates the curve looks like
$$
r^4=r^3\sin3\phi.
$$
So apart from the origin we have the equation 
$$
r=\sin3\phi.
$$
This is the 3-leaved clover, and it does not have a unique tangent at the origin.

Here's what Mathematica gives in response to

```
In[1]:= ContourPlot[(x^2 + y^2)^2 == 3 x^2 y - y^3, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Notice that it has difficulties drawing the curve smoothly near the origin (when using implicit differentiation). This is, of course, due to the singularity.

To get a derivative you need to specify a branch. One way of doing that is to use the parametric representation of the curve that you get from the above polar coordinate equation.

Comment: Thanks for the plot. It illustrates my answer perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If the slope at the origin is $a$,
set $y=ax$ to get

$x^4(1+a^2)^2
=3ax^3-a^3x^3$

or

$x(1+a^2)^2=3a-a^3
=a(3-a^2)$.

Since $x=0$,
we must have
$a=0$ or
$a=\pm \sqrt{3}$.

Without looking at a plot,
this seems to show that
the curve is self-intersecting.

(Added later)

An answer added (and then deleted which is odd for I would have upvoted it)
shows exactly this,
with 3 possible slopes at the origin.

Comment: +1. LOL! Blowing up the curve resolves this type of singularities :-)

Answer (score 0):

if we have $$y=f(x)$$ then we get by differentiating $y$ with respect to $x$
$$2(x^2+y^2)(2x+2yy')=6xy+3x^2y'-3y^2y'$$
Can you finish this?

Comment: I did the same way, but at the end I got dividing by zero. Not?

Comment: then Show us your formula,please

Comment: $y' = (4x^2y+4y^3-3x^2+3y^2)/(6xy-4x^3-4xy^2)$

Comment: @MarufKaraev I took the liberty of adding that calculation to the main post. It may sound strange at first, but we have developed the custom that such things are needed to make questions that look like homework palatable. Hoping that this will lead to your question getting reopened.